# batch que aumente en 1 el valor de un numero dentro de un archivo txt

Tags: batch

Estoy empezando con los scripts para automatizar tareas, y me gustaría hacer un script en batch que lea dentro de un archivo txt un número y a ese número hacerle un incremento en 1, es decir +1. Por ejemplo: El siguiente script me genera un registro de los fotogramas clave y su posición de un video:

```
@echo off
set /P Resolucion=Es 720p o 1080p: 

ffmpeg -i %Resolucion%_000000.mp4 -vf select="eq(pict_type\,PICT_TYPE_I)" -vsync 2 -f null NUL -loglevel debug 2>&1| for /f "tokens=4,8,9 delims=. " %d in ('findstr "pict_type:I"') do echo %d %e.%f>>"IFrames.txt"

pause
```

El resultado mostraría:

```
...
n:0 t:0.000000
n:15 t:0.500000
n:30 t:1.000000
n:45 t:1.500000
n:etc
...
```

PD: el resultado es mucho más largo, llegando hasta n:+5k

Lo que quiero que haga es que el valor que sigue luego de **n** en todas las líneas, es decir "0, 15, 30, 45, etc..." (ignorando t: que no es relevante en este caso) incremente en 1, quedando:

```
...
n:1 t:0.000000
n:16 t:0.500000
n:31 t:1.000000
n:46 t:1.500000
n:etc + 1
```

y así sucesivamente hasta completar la lista que contenga "n:numero". He intentado en python pero no funciona porque busca **n** en la línea, pero no incrementa el valor que contiene.

Estaré muy agradecido con cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes resolverlo con algunos `for` y algunas funciones.

En caso que no sepas, puedes crear una función de la siguiente manera:

```
:Funcion
...
goto :eof
```

En realidad con `:Funcion` lo que haces es crear una etiqueta que puedes usar con `goto` y `call` para moverte a una parte del script. Con `goto :eof` indicas que el script se dirija al final.

Para llamar a la función usas `call`. Para llamar la del ejemplo anterior escribes `call :Funcion` seguido de los parámetros que quieras pasarle.

Puedes acceder a los parámetros mediante el signo de porcentaje y la posición del parámetro. Si llamaras una función con parámetros `call :Funcion a b c`, `%0` corresponde a `:Funcion`, `%1` = a, `%2` = b y `%3` = c. Para obtener todos los parámetros juntos usas `%*`.

Esta información la puedes obtener de la ayuda de los comandos, con `goto /?` y `call /?`.

---

El for es un poco más complicado pero muy útil. Tiene varios modos, pero en el que nos interesa (`/f`) que procesa el archivo línea a línea y funcionamiento así:

```
for /f "opciones" %%variable in (archivo) do intrucciones
```

- La variable tiene que ser de una sola letra, `a`, `b`, `c` o la que prefieras.
- Entre comillas va una serie de opciones que puedes encontrar en `for /?`. Usaré 2:

  - `delims` define delimitadores que separan una línea en diferentes trozos (por defecto espacios y tabulaciones). Por ejemplo, con "delims=-", `a-b-c` en `a`, `b` y `c`.
  - `tokens` define que trozos utilizarás, por defecto el primero. Si quisieras el segundo y el tercero escribirías "tokens=2,3". Si usaste `%%a` en el inicio del for, `%%a` corresponde al primer trozo, `%%b` la siguiente y si tuvieras más `%%c`, `%%d` y así.

---

El código es este:

```
:: Separa cada línea en 2 partes a partir del espacio
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in (archivo.txt) do call :DividirPrimera %%a %%b
:: En %%a se encuentra la primera parte y en %%b la otra

goto :eof

:: Esta función divide la primera parte de la división anterior a partir del :
:: Recibe las dos partes de la separación anterior como parámetros (%1 y %2)
:DividirPrimera
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ("%1") do call :Imprimir %%a %%b %2
:: Nuevamente, en %%a se encuentra la primera parte y en %%b la otra

goto :eof

:: Esta función aumenta el segundo parámetro y reescribe
:: la línea pero con el número aumentado
:Imprimir
set /a aumentado=%2+1
echo %1:%aumentado% %3
goto :eof
```

Para guardar el resultado en un archivo (de preferencia distinto al que está en uso), redirige la salida de los comandos con `>` para crear o sobreescribir el archivo y `>>` para crear o agregar al archivo.

En este caso, solo interesa redirigir el `echo`:

```
echo %1:%aumentado% %3 >> archivo2.txt
```