# Copiar archivos de una carpeta a otras

Tags: windows, cmd, .bat

Tengo una carpeta con 1000 archivos PDF nombrados por un código de DNI. Por otro lado tengo 1000 carpetas nombradas con este mismo número de DNI cada una.
Necesito mover cada archivo a la carpeta que se llama como el mismo archivo.
Para ello he creado un script en BAT pero no se introduce cada archivo en su carpeta, sino que se mueven todos a la carpeta raíz de C.

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b "C:\todos"') DO (
SET "nombre_archivo=%%~nG"

MOVE "C:\todos\%%G" "C:\%nombre_archivo%"
```

)

Este es mi código. Saben qué estoy haciendo mal para que no se introduzca cada archivo en cada carpeta con igual nombre al documento y se mueva a la carpeta raiz?

Comment: Creo que el problema es el mismo que tuvo la persona que escribió [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/558202/169744). Escribí una respuesta que propone el uso de funciones. Hay otras preguntas en las que se propone usar `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`.

Comment: Justo era esto. Muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada. Puedes darle voto a mí respuesta y reportamos esta pregunta como duplicada o también puedes eliminarla tu mismo para que no quede sin responder.